# How can I match this string '-,-,-,9,-'?

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation

I was told to validate the string like this `-,-,-,9,-`

It was separated by `,` and contains 1 number(0-9), others are all `-`

some examples:

`9,-,-,-,-`

`-,-,-,-,9`

`-,-,2,-,-`

How can I match this? And what concepts should I learn in regex?

**Update**

I miss the times, sorry, this string can only contains 5 part,so the length can be only 9,it means a string like below should not be passed:

`-,-,9,-,-,-`

and of course, it should have only one number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[0-9-](?:,[0-9-]){4}$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nM7nT5/5

Comment: above regex will also pass the string which comprises more that one number like `-,-,2,3,4`

Comment: @Jason     `^(?=[,-]*\d[,-]*\d[,-]*$)[0-9-](?:,[0-9-]){4}$`

Answer (score 2):

This ensures that the string must hav atleast one comma and exactly one digit.

```
^(?:\d(?:,-)+|-(?:,-)*,\d(?:,-)*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jH2wZ8/2)

**OR**

```
^(?=\D*(?:^|,)\d(?:,|$)\D*$)[\d-](?:,[\d-])+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jH2wZ8/3)

Comment: I need only five parts, I think this should worked:`^(?=\D*(?:^|,)\d(?:,|$)\D*$)[\d-](?:,[\d-]){4}$`

Comment: @Jason ya exactly, you got that. But try to avoid editing your question after 5 mins grace period.

Comment: Thanks very much, I got that~